# Ruby on Rails Devise - Setup - Already Used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Working through the setup for Devise.

Running

```
rails generate devise admin
```

since admin seems to be the user model setup in my app where I now what it to be SSO auth but I get

```
The name 'Admin' is either already used in your application or reserved by Ruby on Rails. Please choose an alternative or use --skip-collision-check or --force to skip this check and run this generator again.
```

is it OK to force/ignore this? or ?

Comment: Depends on your app.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do. `rails generate devise admin` will create a new Devise model called Admin. It will be a devise model, then a model which logical role would be to replicate a user with admin rights. Are you sure you don't already have an Admin model in your app ? I am not sure what forcing it will do (never occured to me to overwrite a model in Rails) but you may erase your Admin table (not sure) or at least erase any files related to ActiveRecord::Admin and any controller / views named Admins.

Comment: If you already have an Admin model that you want to auth through Devise you don't need that but rather enhance this model with Devise files/methods so it blends into Devise mechanics.